# Truncate the fractional part of a BigDecimal when its scale is zero in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to remove the fractional part of a `BigDecimal` value when its scale has a value of zero. For example,

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.00").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

It would assign `12.00`. I want it to assign only `12` to `value` in such cases.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.000000").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12`,

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.0001").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12`.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.0051").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign`12.01`

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("00.000").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `0`.

---

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.3456").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

should assign `12.35` and alike. Is this possible? What is the best way to do?

Comment: Why is the fraction a problem? Or is it actually the print representation you want to be truncated? In that case you need a NumberFormat.

Comment: Doing so would worth nothing in most cases but it is required in validation with HibernateValidator which doesn't supply a built-in validator to validate precision and scale simultaneously for `BigDecimal`, `float` and `double`. It's for this reason, I have implemented my own custom validator to validate a range of `BigDecimal` values that works on precision and scale. So, when a user enters a value like `12`, it is considered like `12.00` with the scale of 2 which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the crosslink from there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24299/is-this-the-way-of-truncating-the-fractional-part-of-a-bigdecimal-when-its-scale

> Is this possible? What is the best way to do?

Probably `stripTrailingZeros()`.

To check your tests:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    check(truncate("12.000000"), "12");
    check(truncate("12.0001"), "12");
    check(truncate("12.0051"), "12.01");
    check(truncate("12.99"), "12.99");
    check(truncate("12.999"), "13");
    check(truncate("12.3456"), "12.35");
    System.out.println("if we see this message without exceptions, everything is ok");
}

private static BigDecimal truncate(final String text) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(text);
    if (bigDecimal.scale() > 2)
        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(text).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
}

private static void check(final BigDecimal bigDecimal, final String string) {
    if (!bigDecimal.toString().equals(string))
        throw new IllegalStateException("not equal: " + bigDecimal + " and " + string);

}
```

output:

> if we see this message without exceptions, everything is ok

Comment: Good to know a precise, concise and recommended way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you specify with the help of regex and the construction of `BigDecimal`, it is probably not the most efficient way to go about:

```
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12.0000").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.(\\d)0");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
    if (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1).equals("0")) 
            value = value.setScale(0);
        else
            value = value.setScale(1);
    }
```

Note: this also makes 12.100 -> 12.1, I assume that is wanted functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the original value on my own by hand, I have simply tried to apply some conditions like,

```
String text="123.008";
BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text);

if(bigDecimal.scale()>2)
{
    bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}

if(bigDecimal.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)==0)
{
    bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(text).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}

System.out.println("bigDecimal = "+bigDecimal);
```

The first `if` condition checks, if the scale is greater than 2. If so, then perform the rounding operation as specified.

The next `if` condition checks, if the value of the fractional part yields zero. If so, then truncate it. Two BigDecimal objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0 and 2.00) are considered equal by the [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method. Therefore, the condition is satisfied whenever the the value of the fractional part is evaluated to zero.

Otherwise, the original value is left untouched (if the scale is either 1 or 2).

If I'm missing something or it's a wrong thing to implement, then please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
new BigDecimal("12.3456").setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR).stripTrailingZeros()
```